Hosts getting removed from foreman katello on their own
We are using foreman katello for patching and for some reason the hosts are getting removed by "Anonymous Admin" user. I am not able to find any cron or job for the same.
Below is a screenshot of the audit of the host no longer registered
Has some one seen this behavior , i can use some expertise

